# Using Model.object.filter(field='??') to return all in Django

Tags: python, django

So I'm building a search function for my django app. I have a request.GET form from which I'm pulling variables to plug into various filters in my model. My current setup is as follows:

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    grade = request.GET.get('g', '')
    test = Hike.objects.filter(difficulty=grade)
    return render(request, 'hikes/hike_list.html', {
        'test': test,
})
```

So I have users select the difficulty of the hike they are searching for from a multiple choice box, and that plugs into my filter (where difficulty is a field of the Hike model). However, I want an option to not use this filter, and return all (so from the multiple choice box, the user would select "All"). What do I plug in to the filter in order for that filter to be ignored (or just return all)? Or is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to implement that is chaining querysets

```
def search(request):

    qs = Hike.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'GET':

        grade = request.GET.get('g', '')

        if grade:
            qs = qs.filter(difficulty=grade)

    return render(request, 'hikes/hike_list.html', {
            'test': qs,
    })
```

Comment: This is perfect! The other answer seems like it'd work as well, but I'm relatively new to django and this is much simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the user doesn't want to query, just don't include the query parameter when sending the request. then in the backend you just check for a grade

```
grade = request.GET.get('g', '')
test = Hike.objects.all()
if grade:
    test = test.filter(difficulty=grade)
```

Is there an easy way to avoid if statements? You can send a list of query parameters back instead that your model expects and then use unpacking to pass a dictionary of parameters into the queryset.

```
# request.GET could be {difficulty: '1', foo: 'bar'}
if request.GET:
    test = Hike.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

Comment: I'm using multiple filters, though. So I'm chaining them together like so: Hike.objects.filter(difficulty=formgrade, id=formid, elevation=formelevation) etc. where I'm pulling each of those variables from the form. Is there a way to do this without having to create multiple "if" statements?

Comment: @Josh - I've updated my answer, it may be worth creating a different dictionary instead of just request.GET that has better validation

Comment: That's what the validation aspect of `django.forms` is typically used for even if you're not using it to render HTML

Comment: This looks like it'll do the trick. This is my first experience building something like this, but it seems like it should work. I'll put some time into it and see how it goes. Thank you for your help!